# Lambda returns dynamo values as "UserId: [Object]"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I just did a lamda GET request for the first time and the execution log in lambda looks like this instead of the actual values in the table. There's only 6 items in the dynamodb table so it got that part right, but I just need the values.        How can I fix this?

```
Response:
"All data is here"

Request ID:
"63df4b9d-6c80-4b15-b649-71d6a70c33b0"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 63df4b9d-6c80-4b15-b649-71d6a70c33b0 Version: $LATEST
2019-09-15T17:11:30.347Z    63df4b9d-6c80-4b15-b649-71d6a70c33b0    INFO    { Items:
   [ { UserId: [Object],
       Height: [Object],
       Income: [Object],
       Age: [Object] },
     { UserId: [Object],
       Height: [Object],
       Income: [Object],
       Age: [Object] },
     { UserId: [Object],
       Height: [Object],
       Income: [Object],
       Age: [Object] },
     { UserId: [Object],
       Height: [Object],
       Income: [Object],
       Age: [Object] },
     { UserId: [Object],
       Height: [Object],
       Income: [Object],
       Age: [Object] },
     { UserId: [Object],
       Height: [Object],
       Income: [Object],
       Age: [Object] } ],
  Count: 6,
  ScannedCount: 6 }
END RequestId: 63df4b9d-6c80-4b15-b649-71d6a70c33b0
REPORT RequestId: 63df4b9d-6c80-4b15-b649-71d6a70c33b0  Duration: 795.77 ms Billed Duration: 800 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 92 MB  Init Duration: 353.05 ms    
XRAY TraceId: 1-5d7e70c1-b2c9f084fcb1b9a0385558aa   SegmentId: 0db262e76ca3b887 Sampled: false
```

LAMBDA Function

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler =(event, context, callback) => {
const type = event.type;
if(type =='all'){
    const params = {
        TableName: 'compare-yourself'
        };
        dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
            }else {
                console.log(data);
                callback(null, data);

            }

        })

    callback(null, "All data is here");
}
if(type =='single'){


    callback(null, "Single user data is here");
}else{
    callback(null, 'Hello from Labmda');
}
callback()
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line,

> console.log(data);

to

> console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

You need to stringify the data if you want to print it.

Also you need to remove, `callback(null, "All data is here");` otherwise you are issuing double callback to the caller that lambda is complete.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's makes sense